# Probability of line segments intersecting on a plane - A generalization to Buffon's needle problem

Tags: probability, integration, geometry, geometric-probability

I came up with this problem:

> If I draw a length 1 line segment randomly, then draw another one,
> what's the probability that they'll intersect?

More precisely,

> Consider a rectangular area of size $w\times l$ with periodic boundary
> conditions, where $w\ge 2,l\ge 2$. Draw two length 1 line segments
> randomly. Here, by randomly it means, first choose a random point with
> uniform distribution over the rectangular area, then from the circle
> that is centered at the first point with radius one, randomly choose a
> point with uniform distribution. These two points are the end points
> of the line segment.

> Question: What's the probability that the
> two line segments intersect?

The solution can be found by simply integrating the probability densities, which gives $p=\frac{1}{A}\times 4\times\frac{1}{2\pi}(p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4)$,
where $A=lw$ is the area, and

$p_1=\int_0^1 rdr\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\theta-\sin^{-1}(r\sin\theta)d\theta$

$p_2=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1dx\int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{y}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1-x}{y}dy$

$\quad=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 rdr\int_{\sin^{-1}\frac{r}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\theta+\tan^{-1}\frac{1-r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta}d\theta$

$p_3=\int_0^1 rdr\int_0^{\sin^{-1}\frac{r}{2}}\theta+\cos^{-1}(r\cos\theta)d\theta$

$p_4=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\int_\sqrt{1-x^2}^1 2\cos^{-1}y\ dy$

And the results are

$p_1=\frac{1}{4}$

$p_2=0.583664$

$p_3=0.155138$

$p_4=0.011197 =\frac{1}{72}(27 - 3 \sqrt 3 \pi - \pi^2)$

Details can be found on [my blog post](https://hyper-meta.blogspot.com/2023/10/probability-of-line-segments.html).

The summation of these numbers is 0.999999, which is probably not a coincidence. My questions are,

1. Do they sum up to exactly 1, so that the probability is exactly $\frac{2}{\pi A}$? (Probably true, just need to find the exact integration value.) (✓ Proved)
2. **Is there an easier and more intuitive way to prove this?**
3. **How can this be generalized?**

I searched similar problems but I didn't find anything quite the same.

Considering that Buffon's needle problem has probability $\frac{2l}{\pi t}$, are they somehow related?

A more general description of this problem can be stated as the following:

> Assuming there is a random uniform distribution with
> density $\frac{1}{A}$ of line segments with length 1 on the 2D plane.
> More precisely, the distribution is, the middle points of the line
> segments are uniformly distributed on the plane with density
> $\frac{1}{A}$ and the angles are also uniformly distributed from 0 to
> $2\pi$.
>
> Then, if we draw another line segment of length one randomly, as
> described in the beginning, the expected number of intersections between
> this line segment and the line segments in the "background" is
> $\frac{2}{\pi A}$.

---

Edit:

I think, indeed, **the Buffon's needle problem can be seen as a special case of this problem**.

If we see each line as an infinite chain of length 1 line segments, and the distance between the lines is $t$, then each line segment occupies an area $t$, thus the expectation of the number of intersections between a length 1 needle with the lines is $\frac{2}{\pi A}=\frac{2}{\pi t}$. Due to the linearity of expectation, a length $l$ needle will have expectation $\frac{2l}{\pi t}$. When $l\leq t$, there can be at most one intersection, thus this is the probability of them intersecting.

---

Update 2023.10.30

After seeing @Claude Leibovici's answer, it seems that the integration of $p_3$ is particularly complicated, so I thought maybe doing it in the other direction is easier.

If we integrate $r$ first instead,the interval of $\theta$ is $[0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$ and the interval of $r$ is $[2\sin\theta,1]$. The integration is

$p_3=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}d\theta\int_{2\sin\theta}^1 (\theta+\cos^{-1}(r\cos\theta))rdr$
$\quad=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\theta}{2}(1-4\sin^2\theta)+\left[\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{2}\cos^{-1}(r\cos\theta)+\frac{1}{4}\sin^{-1}(r\cos\theta)-\frac{r\cos\theta}{4}\sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2\theta}\right]_{2\sin\theta}^1\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta$
$\quad=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\theta}{2}(1-4\sin^2\theta)+\left(\theta\frac{\cos^2\theta}{2}+\frac{1}{4}(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)-\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{4}-\frac{\sin^2 2\theta}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta)-\frac{1}{4}(2\theta)+\frac{\sin 2\theta \cos 2\theta}{4}\right)\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta$

which is exactly $\frac{1}{36}(9+3\sqrt 3\pi-2\pi^2)$.

Combined with the other exact results, I think it's safe to say that the probability equals $\frac{2}{\pi A}$ is proved?

---

Some variations that I can think of:

1. Change background line segments into disks of radius 1. (Should be $\frac{1}{A}\left(\pi+\int_1^{\sqrt 2} 2r\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)dr+\int_{\sqrt 2}^2 2r\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)dr\right)=\frac{\pi+2}{A}$ if my calculation is correct.)
2. Disks of radius R.
3. Empty circles of radius R<0.5. (Expected number of intersections, or probability of intersecting.)
4. Empty circles of radius R>0.5. (Expected number of intersections, or probability of intersecting.)

Are the expected numbers for cases 3 and 4 the same as considering the circle as the limit of an $n$-gon as $n\rightarrow\infty$? From the linearity of expectation, I expect that... If these problems turn out to be interesting, I'll post them in a seperate question.

Comment: Nice work for sure and (+1).

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/whypi.pdf

Comment: @EthanBolker This is called "[Buffon's noodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle)" problem, a variation of the needle problem. I found this entry when I read through the needle problem, and I was thinking that maybe the Barbier's theorem is relevant to this problem. But after reading it more carefully, I realized that it's still the "shapes intersecting infinite lines that are evenly spaced" problem, so it doesn't provide much new info. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

$$p_2=\frac{1}{72} \left(9-3 \sqrt{3} \pi +5 \pi ^2\right)$$
$$p_3=\frac{1}{36} \left(9+3 \sqrt{3} \pi -2 \pi ^2\right)$$
$$p_4=\frac{1}{72}\left(27 - 3 \sqrt 3 \pi - \pi^2\right)$$

I did not obtain $p_3$ directly but  computed the integral to high accuracy and searched for $(a,b,c)$ such that
$$0.15513848544247898382438117552853053666469992828759\cdots$$ $$=\frac{1}{72}\left(a + 3\sqrt 3 \pi b+c \pi^2\right)$$ over integers (three loops).

So $(p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4)$ is strictly equal to $1$.

**Edit**

In the middle of my work, I also found that

$$\int_0^1 r\,dr\int_0^{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}\theta\,d \theta=\frac{1}{144} \left(-18+6 \sqrt{3} \pi -\pi ^2\right)$$  Too many common features !

**Update**

The real problem is
$$\int_0^{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}\cos ^{-1}(r \cos (\theta ))\,d \theta=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)-$$ $$ \int_0^{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (2 n)!\, r^{2 n+1} }{4^n\,(2 n+1)\, (n!)^2}\cos ^{2 n+1}(\theta)$$

The problem is that

$$\int_0^{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)}\cos ^{2 n+1}(\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}-B_{1-\frac{r^2}{4}}\left(n+1,\frac {1}{2}\right)\right)$$

SO, for $p_3$ we end with the monster
$$p_3=\frac{1}{48} \left(12+24 \left(\sqrt{3}-2\right) \pi +\pi^2\right)+$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (2 n)!}{2^{2 n+1}(2 n+1) (n!)^2}\int_0^1 r^{2 n+2} B_{1-\frac{r^2}{4}}\left(n+1,\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dr$$

Only the first term of the summation has a closed form value $(\frac 5 {24})$ but the summation converges quite fast.

*Hoping no sign errors !*

Comment: If it helps, I get $$ \frac{d}{dr} \int_0^{\sin^{-1}(r/2)} \cos^{-1}(r \cos \theta)\, d\theta = \frac{\cos^{-1}\left(r \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{4}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{4}}} + \frac{\ln(1-r^2) - \ln 2}{2r} $$

Comment: @aschepler. Thank you but the problem moves after. This integral is a nightmare. Cheers :-)

Comment: wow this seems really complicated. What are the $B$ functions here? Are they Bernoulli polynomials? I don't know they can take non-integer indices.

Also, how did you get the high accuracy integral? Does the GMP library provide such precision?

Regarding the integration itself, I found a work around, just integrate $r$ first, it's much easier! I updated it in the description.

Comment: @YiJiang. The incomplete beta functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I see, thanks!